# Combine two rows of data using LINQ/SQL

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2005

I have a situation where my query returns the following two rows:

```
UserName  ID  Designation   RoleID

shd.1234   3        1          2

shd.1234   3        1          5
```

I am able to display these results in a Jqgrid using LINQ.

However I want to display it as under in a single row:(if RoleID is 5, display it in another column in the same row.)

```
UserName  ID  Designation   RoleID    AdditionalRoleID

shd.1234   3        1          2            5
```

My current query is something like this:

```
empDetails = (from u in ObjectContext.USERS
              join ed in ObjectContext.USERS_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS on u.UserID equals ed.UserID
              join r in ObjectContext.ROLES_FOR_USERS on u.UserID equals r.UserID
              join ro in ObjectContext.ROLES on r.RoleID equals ro.RoleID
              where (r.HospitalID == Context.CurrentUser.HIdentity.HospitalID)
              where(r.RoleID!= 4)
              select new Models.AdminModelSettings.EmployeeDetailsForGivenHospital
              {
                  UserName = u.UserName,
                  EmployeeId = ed.ID,
                  EmployeeDesignation = ed.Designation,
                  RoleID = r.RoleID,
                  RoleName = r.RoleID == 1 || r.RoleID == 2 || r.RoleID == 3 ? ro.RoleName : null,
                  AdditionalRole = r.RoleID == 5  ? ro.RoleName : null
              }).ToList();
```

I would please like to know how this can be done in SQL/LINQ.

Comment: then what if there is a third row with RoleID = 8? Yet another column? Where does it end?

Comment: There are only 4 ID's 1,2,3,5. 1,2,3 go in first column, 5 in second column.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:  I've improved the code so it will do all of the work in SQL instead of returning the results and then performing the grouping.**

This should do the trick!

The key part is where we order the rows by RoleID and then group the rows by ID.  It assumes that you only have a Role and an Additional Role, i.e. it won't select an AdditionalRole2 or AdditionalRole3, etc...

```
var empDetails = from u in ObjectContext.USERS 
                 join ed in ObjectContext.USERS_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS on u.UserID equals ed.UserID 
                 join r in ObjectContext.ROLES_FOR_USERS on u.UserID equals r.UserID 
                 join ro in ObjectContext.ROLES on r.RoleID equals ro.RoleID 
                 where (r.HospitalID == Context.CurrentUser.HIdentity.HospitalID) 
                 where(r.RoleID!= 4) 
                 select new Models.AdminModelSettings.EmployeeDetailsForGivenHospital 
                 { 
                     UserName = u.UserName, 
                     EmployeeId = ed.ID, 
                     EmployeeDesignation = ed.Designation, 
                     RoleID = r.RoleID, 
                     RoleName = r.RoleID == 1 || r.RoleID == 2 || r.RoleID == 3 ? ro.RoleName : null
                 });

var roleIDs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

//group our results and order the group by the role id
var temp = empDetails.GroupBy(row => row.ID).Select(g => new { First = g.FirstOrDefault(r => roleIDs.Contains(r.RoleID)), Last = g.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleID == 5) });

//select the data into the shape that we want
var query = temp.Select(result => new Models.AdminModelSettings.EmployeeDetailsForGivenHospital
{
    UserName = (result.First ?? result.Last).UserName,
    EmployeeId = (result.First ?? result.Last).ID,
    EmployeeDesignation = (result.First ?? result.Last).Designation,
    RoleID = (result.First == null) ? (int?)null : result.First.RoleID,
    AdditionalRoleID = (result.Last == null) ? (int?)null : result.Last.RoleID
});
```

Comment: 1.What do I return now? Earlier it was empDetails.AsQueryable(); 2. If I give a .ToList() at the end of query, I get the same value for RoleID and AdditionalRoleID in all rows.

Comment: It should only give the same value for RoleID and AdditionalRoleID if there is only 1 RoleID for the specified employee.

Comment: If you change the select to select your Models.AdminModelSettings.EmployeeDetailsForGivenHospital class, you'll be able to return a list of them or a queryable or whatever you'd like.

Comment: You said it will give the same value for RoleID and AdditionalRoleID if there is only 1 RoleID for the specified employee. If RoleID is 5, I want RoleID blank and AdditionalRoleID 5; else I want AdditionalRoleID blank and RoleID showing 1,2 or 3.

Comment: I've updated the code to select your EmployeeDetailsForGivenHospital class.  Are there any other problem points?

Comment: If there is both 5 and one of 1,2, or 3 then both columns must be populated in the same row. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the code, that should do the trick.  Let me know if there are any more points you'd like addressing.

Comment: I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object for the var query code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I have instantiated query variable also similar to empDetails. Just a sec, I'll see. Where Is the update?

Comment: No, it isn't working. I am still seeing 4 rows instead of 3. The rows are not getting combined.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing the data I can't track down where the problem is coming from.  The query works against the test data that I've been running it against, I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: There are 4 rows in all two for each user. For one user, the roles are 2 and 3 and for the other they are 1 and 5. That's all really that I can tell you. Could you please tell me about your test data?